# Estimating a true mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means, parameter-estimation

> A sample average is 54 while a sample size is 159. If a population deviation is 19 estimate a true mean that should be accurate with a probability of 99%.

So I started with $(1-0.99)/2 = 1/200$ then I started to look in the Z-Table for the Z-Score. I came up with the value of 0.1841 which I am not sure is correct. After that I substracted $54-0.1841=53.8159$ and added $54+0.1841=54.1841$ to get that CI is (53.8159,54.1841). Is this correct, or am I missing the complete idea of the task?

Comment: No, this is not correct. The probability of standard normal $Z$ be greater than  $0.9$ is $0.1841$. This is not your case. You need to find a value such that $Z$ is greater it with probability $1/200$. Note also that you did not use population deviation and sample size at all. Look at the CI formula in your book/lecture notes.

Comment: I believe you mean _population standard deviation_ and _confidence interval._ Values $\pm 2.576$ cut probability .005 from the lower and upper tails of the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlooking awkward terminology: A 99% *confidence* interval for the
population mean $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 2.576\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$
I got the interval $(51.9571, 56.0429),$ but you should check my
arithmetic.

Comment: That is exactly what I got after various attempts. Thank you !